# Background Image not following cover rule

Tags: html, css, styles

My background image is scaling down as the window width decreases. I want the image to be full image regardless of the display. How would I implement that? The following code scales the image, then starts only show a section.

```
header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
min-height: auto;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
background-position: center !important;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Change the lines that reference 'cover' and give them hardcoded values just to test whether cover is the problem or not

Comment: I'm not sure this question is clear. If you want to see the full image, you'll end up with aspect ratio mismatches at various viewport sizes, like watching a 16:9 film on a 4:3 screen. If that's what you want, then you need `contain`, not `cover`. Otherwise, the question requires more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, simply set your header width to the width of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to full width background image for your header(Hero Header).

Try these code examples.
[Demo Link](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)